# How to install SQL Server LocalDB with my application?

Tags: vb.net, .net-4.5, silent-installer, sql-server-2014-localdb

I have developed an application in vb.net 4.5 with VS2015 and I am using InstallShield Limited Edition to create the MSI installation file.

Some of the final users don't have internet, so I need to include the `SQLLocalDB.msi` and install it silently.

I can't find a single sample for this, it should be a common scenario right?

Comment: More info but not a duplicate here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655362/localdb-deployment-on-client-pc

Comment: There's an answer at [Can ClickOnce or InstallShield setup SQL Server or SQL Server Express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34553647/can-clickonce-or-installshield-setup-sql-server-or-sql-server-express) that might help.

Comment: I can't use ClickOnce since some of my clients don't have internet access

Comment: Firstly, you shouldn't be looking to install LocalDB, which is intended for developers. You should be looking to install SQL Server Express.  Secondly, the fact that your users don't have internet access is irrelevant to whether you use ClickOnce.  You can provide a ClickOnce installer on a disk or flash drive, just like any other installer.  Internet is an advantage for automatic updates but not essential. Also, Windows Installer and ClickOnce can use the exact same prerequisite packages to bootstrap third-party installers, so installing SQL Server Express is basically the same in both cases.

Comment: LocalDB also is intended to be distributed on light applications, SQL Express consumes much higher RAM than LocalDB.You are right about ClickOnce, but I would like to have all included in a single MSI.

Answer (score 4):

Well, since I couldn't get an answer, I ended up including the SQLLocalDB.msi to the VS project and mark the file as "Required", so when my application starts, check if database is installed and if not, starts the msi installation in silent mode.